# is this possible with facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am new to FB apps, but before reading the docs I need to make sure this is possible.

Can I make it so that every time a user updates his status, and has granted my application access, it will automatically send a message to my application to update a database with his status, or maybe call a function?

You could think of it as "passing a message" ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT message
FROM   status
WHERE  uid=me() (PUT USER ID HERE)
```

I don't how you would go about being notified the second this happens every time, but if you routinely query this you will get all of the relevant statuses.

Comment: That could work, but does the user need to be logged in for me to see their info?

Comment: You have to be more specific than "logged in." It does not matter if they have Facebook open on their computer- only if they have authorized your app.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably find it much easier to use the realtime updates API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ - rather than having to keep making FQL queries.